# Could a lower bandwidth or rise time oscilloscope be used for measuring a stable phase shift between two channels?

Tags: oscilloscope, frequency-measurement, phase-shift

I’m trying to design an experimental setup to measure the speed of EM waves transmitted from a small solenoid antenna (It won’t transmit effectively but I have to make the antennas more “point like”) driven by a common emitter based Colpitts oscillator at varying frequencies between 1MHz and 10 MHz; and recieved by an equivalent solenoid antenna connected to an adjustable capacitor tank circuit (or maybe a CE amplifier if need be) or maybe simply grounded. Antennas will be positioned at varying distances from 0.4 m to 2 m; very short electrical distances.

I will be measuring voltage and current waveforms (sine) at both sides simultaneously. Because of the ratio of the distance between the solenoids to the wavelengths, I expect that the measured waveforms (when superposed together on screen) will look like almost completely overlaping. Therefore, an oscilloscope which would discriminate the phase differences with fine enough resolution/accuracy in time  is required.

[image]

First thought was that, if the delay time expected is “td” then an oscilloscope with a bandwidth like maybe “(1/2td) Hertz” would do well here (the waveforms could be seen without considerable distortion in terms of time). For 1 m distance, that would make 150 MHz (at -3dB) but for shorter distances that wouldn’t be affordable for me.

The next specification of interest is the rise time. It’s often recommended to choose a scope with a rise time less than 1/3 of the rise time to be measured and that’s even less affordable.

These tips seem to be based on the assumption that the measured waveforms would be non-repeating (would need “triggers” to indicate them). But I will be measuring periodic waveforms. Could that be an advantage?

Assuming that the sampling rate is good enough, is there a “trick” to using cheaper scopes for measurements on stable sine waveforms?

One could suggest “why not simply increase the scale of the setup, like in the phase shift method to measure distances, and get away with it?”. I will hopefully continue these measurements with other antenna types sometimes in the “very” near field so sooner or later I will be facing this problem.

Comment: Can you say more about why you would need to measure such small delays relative to your signal's period?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate optical phenomena on a larger scale. But not only this. My understanding of electromagnetism is incomplete and primitive so to say. I can't make sense of transverse waves without longitudinal waves. These are sometimes called near-field or evanescent wavesi Tesla waves or dielectric waves. I know this is not really solid science after a point but to me that point is blurry. These longitudinal waves are implied to be faster than speed of light.

Comment: This is a huge subject. I could suggest investigating the works of  Konstantin Meyl,the evanescent waves, googling many articles explaining "near field propagation faster than light", W.Minto's "hydronic waves" and Tesla's notes on "radiant energy" and how he calculated his "Tesla waves" to be propagating at varying speeds exceeding that of light at some conditions. Trying to relate them with photons, the double slit experiment and classical electromagnetism and to make sense out of all the confusion, I got fed up with it.

Comment: That's why I must be "asking some cleverly designed questions to the nature in person". With no offense meant to your nickname of course.

Comment: ah I remember you, you were the esoteric EM guy with barely a cue!

Comment: Just use a spectrum analyzer.

Comment: Network analyzer.

Comment: Can use also a classic dual channel "downshift" (mixer) frequency change ... or a fast double "channel sampler" well synchronized ... then work with low frequencies waves ... :-)

Answer (score -1):

If the scope's bandwidth is wide enough to properly display the signal, then it will measure the phase accurately.

Point in case: I used a PC sound card sampling at 192k to measure phase shifts between two 48kHz sine waves, down to much less than 1ns, using a software IQ detector.